# Multithreading and SQL Query

Tags: c#, sql, multithreading

Can somebody provide a sample to query the sql database on multithreaded basis? Like, I have 20k records in DB and each 1000 records has to undergo a forloop. My current code is like below.
all rows has been read to lstDevice and it has 20k items

```
       if (lstDevice.Count > 0)
            {

                for (int i = 0; i < lstDevice.Count; i += 1000)
                {
                    splitList.Add(lstDevice.Skip(i).Take(1000).ToList<DeviceHelper>());
                }

                var tasks = new Task[splitList.Count];
                int count = 0;
                foreach (List<DeviceHelper> lst in splitList)
                {
                    tasks[count] = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
                    {
                        QueueNotifications(lst, pMessage, pSubject,              pNotificationType,            push);
                    },
                        TaskCreationOptions.None);
                    count++;
                }
             }
```

And now i want to modify it to use multithreading to fetch 1000 records and do foreach of that 1000 records, which is basically the second foreach of the code posted.

Comment: why do you want to do something like this? It will still take the same amount of time because it will get qued on the server database anyways

Comment: Don't spam the database with parallel queries... It it might be that you *first* want to query the database (synchronous, not async) put your db results in a collection and close the db connection. *After that* you do asynchronous multithreaded processing on the items in your collection.